# Determine limits of a server

Tags: wordpress, server

I use a root server with following specs:

```
120GB RAM
24 virtual cores
1.5TB HDD
```

This server runs one Wordpress blog. No particularly heavy plugins are being used.

During highest traffic period (Sunday evening) Google Analytics realtime stats show 100 users online.

phpMyAdmin stats show during such period:

```
CPU usage: 15%
RAM usage: 16GB (104GB free)
```

This (still low) traffic causes the server to load pages twice as slow and its rather difficult to determine whether its a hardware limitation or poor software optimization.

Generally speaking, what traffic should such server be able to manage while running Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described seems adequate.

I have found that sometimes a single poorly written plugin will slow a website down and bog down a server.  Can you eliminate any plugins that aren't needed or disable one plugin at a time to see if performance improves?

Are you using any form of [caching](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/Caching), like [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)?  This will likely help things out as well.

Comment: I have done a lot of testing especially disabling plugins and also playing around with caching plugins it didnt make much of a difference. I guess the question is: Is this hardware capable of handling 100, 500, 1000, 5000 users at once? If not perhaps I should start thinking about a more scalable platform such as Google / Amazon right?

Comment: It would be worth while to [optimize MySQL](http://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/mysqltuner) and your web server, [apache](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache-tips-and-tricks/tuning-your-apache-server), to handle higher concurrent users. It is possible that this is where you bottle neck is with higher traffic.  There are also a lot of deeper [server config](http://serverfault.com/questions/219721/optimize-apache-for-10k-wordpress-views-a-day-on-2gb-ram-e6500-cpu) related information over on stackfault.  If this has been helpful, please consider accepting the answer given.